# When using vue to create an Excel Add-in. How can I compute a property based on data on the excel notebook?

Tags: javascript, excel, sharepoint, office365, office-js

I want to get a list of the names of the sheets to create a drop drop down in my add in. I tried to do it via a a computed property but you cant run async functions to interact whit excel when computing a property. Right now im calling a method when computing the property but I think its not running the code in the excel.run. In the code bellow only the a and the d get pushed to the array.

```js
computed: {
    formats: function () {
      return this.getSheetNames()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getSheetNames () {
      var sheetNames = ['a']
      window.Excel.run(async (context, sheetNames) => {
        let promise = Promise.resolve(['b'])
        let list = await promise
        sheetNames.push(list)
        sheetNames.push('c')
      })
      sheetNames.push('d')
      return sheetNames
    }
```

Comment: If my reply helps you, please mark the reply as answer, it will make others who stuck with the similar issue easier to search for valid solutions in this forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the code below:

```
Window.Excel.run(async(context) {
    var sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
    sheets.load("items/name");
    var sheetNames = [];
    return context.sync()
        .then(function () {
            if (sheets.items.length > 1) {
                console.log(`There are ${sheets.items.length} worksheets in the workbook:`);
            } else {
                console.log(`There is one worksheet in the workbook:`);
            }
            for (var i in sheets.items) {
                sheetNames.push(sheets.items[i].name); 

            }
        });
})
```

For more information, please review the following link:

[Get worksheets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-worksheets)